# Errors when creating conda environment on OSX

Tags: anaconda, conda

This has worked for me in the past, but creating a conda environment from a yml file isn't working for me anymore. Any idea how to fix it? I have conda 4.3.29.

Attempt 1:

```
conda create --file CondaEnvironment.yml3 --name temp1 

CondaValueError: could not parse 'name: notebook' in: CondaEnvironment.yml3
```

Attempt 2:

```
conda create -n temp1 CondaEnvironment.yml3 
Fetching package metadata .............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - condaenvironment.yml3

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Attempt 3

```
conda create CondaEnvironment.yml3 

CondaValueError: either -n NAME or -p PREFIX option required,
try "conda create -h" for more details
```

Comment: What are the contents of `CondaEnvironment.yml3`?

Comment: I tried puttting them in the original message, but then Stack Overflow complained that the question had too much code and rejected it. And it's too long for a comment. Will upload somewhere and add a link to it. Is there a best-practices way of doing that?

Comment: You could link to a GitHub Gist, or pastebin, or something. If you post it somewhere, I'll be able to edit it into the post, I think

Comment: Additional info can be found here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2071

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `conda env create` command rather than the `conda create` command

```
conda env create -f CondaEnvironment.yml3
```